# 502 Bad Gateway on localhost Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, 502

I'm trying to run a Drupal 7 multi-site install on my Mac (10.12.6).

My directory setup:

```
~/Sites/index.html
~/Sites/drupal/docroot/sites/site1
~/Sites/drupal/docroot/sites/site2
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1    site1.local
127.0.0.1    site2.local
```

If I go to `http://localhost`, I see my `index.html` file, no problem. If I visit `http://site1.local` or `http://site2.local`, I get 502 Bad Gateway.

in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`:

- I'm listening on Port 80
- `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory` are set to `/Users/me/Sites/`
- `AllowOverride` is set to `All`
- `ServerName` is set to `localhost`, user & group are set to `me`, `staff`

And the following are uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My vhosts file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/me/Sites
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/me/Sites/drupal/docroot
    ServerName site1.local
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/site1cms-error.log
  Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT local
  SetEnv AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT local
  SetEnv AH_SITE_GROUP local
  <Directory /Users/me/Sites/drupal/docroot>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/me/Sites/drupal/docroot
    ServerName site2.local
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/site2cms-error.log
  Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT local
  SetEnv AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT local
  SetEnv AH_SITE_GROUP local
  <Directory /Users/me/Sites/drupal/docroot>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I `curl site1.local` from terminal the site loads fine, but loading from Chrome or Safari I get the 502.

I tried `sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill` in case some other apps were listening on port 80 but it didn't help.

I've looked in the Apache logs and the custom logs I created above, nothing is recorded.

Running MySql 5.7, PHP 5.6, Apache 2.4. Tried restarting all services.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know drupal, but why site1.local doesn't has ~/Sites/drupal/docroot/sites/site1 as document root?

Comment: No, docroot handles the routing for both sites. Confirmed because a coworker has it this way and it works on his machine. And I’ve tried it the other way and it doesn’t.

Comment: Intent of installing all this staff on your mac, try to use vagrant.

Comment: Spent several days doing vagrant, only to fail. The db is too large, 50 GB. I was able to resize the box image to accommodate it but all operations inside were glacial. Everyone insisted I give up on vagrant.

Comment: Are you running chrome or safari on the server itself or on another system?

Comment: Same system. One Mac.

Comment: /etc/hosts: one line or two? I don't see localhost in there.

Comment: I've tried both one line and two. It works either way. I can ping both and get responses, so it's not `/etc/hosts`. Again I can also curl from terminal and get the correct page back, not 502

Comment: So, let's have a look at the browsers then.  Clear their cache, check their network settings (proxy?).

Comment: Replace index.php (move it aside) with a simple one that just runs phpinfo(). What do you find? If you're getting a 502, then the application is just being very slow and has timed out. Note that httpd access logs are generated after the request has been served. You don't seem to have any CustomLog set (from what you've posted). Also useful: you can put a LogLevel DEBUG inside the scope (VirtualHost, Directory, Location etc).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I think you're onto something. I'd cleared my caches and rebooted multiple times to no effect, but I just opened my Mac from a sleep state and the sites are working again...no changes made. Maybe something timed out? Why would browsers say 502 but it curls fine from the terminal on the same machine?

Comment: For example: a browser can put www in front of the domain you request. Who knows with Google what a browser may be up to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was on a (work-mandated) Cisco VPN. Disconnected from said VPN and 502 error disappears.

An edge-case but FYI for anyone else who encounters this problem in the future.